# vue-router: this.$router.push not working when updating query

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I want to update query on url. But, $router.push does not updating url. `disp` is different value for each call. Why?

```
handle: function(disp) {
    let route = Object.assign({}, this.$route);
    route.query.disp = disp;
    this.$router.push(route);
},
```

versions.

```
"vue": "^2.5.17",
"vue-router": "^3.0.1",
```

route (console.log)

[image]

Comment: can you do a console.log of route before the `push()` to check values of the object

Comment: I add picture of console.log with route.

Comment: not sure, everything seems to be correct overall, have you tried to navigate by using an object directly? `this.$router.push({ name: 'component name'})` to make sure router is configured correctly

Comment: I see `console.log(this.$route.query.disp);`. `$route.query.disp` is updated. But url is not updating.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't try to push to the route object. Instead you should use one of these:

```
// literal string path
router.push('home')

// object
router.push({ path: 'home' })

// named route
router.push({ name: 'user', params: { userId: 123 }})

// with query, resulting in /register?plan=private
router.push({ path: 'register', query: { plan: 'private' }})
```

In your case:

```
this.$router.push({path: this.$route.path, query: {disp: disp}})
```

Comment: I tryed `this.$router.push({ name: 'name', params: { page: this.$route.params.page }, query: { disp: [dispLines,] } });`. But, url is not updating. But, this.$route was updated by push parameters. Why url is not updating?

Comment: And I tryed `this.$router.push({ path: '/posts', query: { disp: [dispLines,] } });`. That is not working.

Comment: It does not work for me as well... when I am pushing same path, url is not getting updated, when I push another path it works well.. but I want to stay on same path, just need to update param :/ 
        "vue": "2.6.10",
        "vue-router": "3.0.6"

Comment: I have found my problem... this answer works fine I have test it here https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-9o3u5. My problem is that I am copying query params between routes on each route change and it was the cause.