# Vue router push not updating the query in nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, nuxt.js

I have problem with vue-router-query I'm using  a click event to navigate to filter page and append the URL query to it this is the sent query function in methods

```
search(){
   this.$router.push({
     name: 'query',
     query: this.query
    })
}
```

the ' this.query ' is the object that holds all query data so after I click the button and the method search runs he navigate to the filter page and this the URL `localhost/query?data=1` now here is the problem I can't update the `data` query if I want to add other element to the object the URL doesn't updated and here the filter page search method ,

```
updateSearchUrl(){
    this.$router.push({
        name: 'query',
        query: this.query
    })
}
```

It is the same but I can't under stand why it doesn't work but if I tried static data not a dynamic object it works so I'm kind stuck over here the problem in the `this.$router.push` or from the object `query`

What I'm trying to do here is just to update the query URL and I tried a few solution and didn't work like this URL [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52973554/vue-router-this-router-push-not-working-when-updating-query) and also tried to use `replace` instead of `push` in `$router`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
this.$router.push({
    name: 'query',
    query: Object.assign({}, this.query)
})
```

Comment: That work just fine when I reload the page but when I go to route to other router is doesn't update the query URL this is my pages structure 
       ` --- page 
           -- query
            - index
       `

Comment: The problem `this.query` is a props I to a child component and these function in the question up there is in this child component and try to update the query URL by router path it's works but I know it's not the solution so could you tell me how to update the query to the same route ?